# Looking for Cipher Help

Tags: cipher

This cipher has me vexed.  FOOTOOLTLTLBDCLOLTLTJBFTOCFTOOOCDC.  There appear to be too many Os(and no other vowels) to be a transposition cipher.  The coindidence index is 14.75, which is quite high, but with the repeating LTLT and the triple O no substitutions have made sense.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE. Is this cipher from an outside source? If so make sure you have permission to post it on other locations and include the source.

Comment: A friend created it and gave to us to solve, so we should be ok.

Comment: To add a touch more context, this message was provided to our DnD group by the DM at the bottom of a summons for help.  All of us have been stumped.

Comment: Only 8 different letters are used. Is this a cipher in octal?

Comment: Could it be related to the rulebook for the version you play? Like a shorthand for a pre-existing set of words like chapter titles, character names, a known phrase...?

Comment: It could be Octal, though not sure how that would work.  2 words were bolded in the message, Cabot, and Fjold.

Comment: Can you share a little more about the context?  They may have given you some hints in the locations or character names that could be clues to answer this puzzle.

Answer (score 9):

Okay I think the message is

> Don't trust the Kenku.

Reasoning

> As you pointed out, it looks like the letters are actually broken into pairs rather than encrypted singly (see the frequency of the pair LT) so let's break the ciphered text up into pairs of letters 
>  FO OT OO LT LT LB DC LO LT LT JB FT OC FT OO OC DC 
>  This looks rather likes a [Polybius square cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polybius_square) where we are using letters instead of numbers. I played around a bit to try to determine the order of the letters on both axes and determined that a very nice thing happens if we use the order **CABOT** on the horizontal and **FJOLD** on the vertical axis (also **Cabot Fjold** sounds like it could be a place in DnD). 
>  In particular, the Polybius square looks as follows 
>  
>      **C A B O T** 
>  **F**  A B C D E
>  **J**  F G H  I  J 
>  **O** K L M N O 
>  **L** P Q R S  T 
>  **D** U V W X Y 
>  To decipher, for any individual pair of letters, you take the first letter on the vertical bold axis and the second letter on the horizontal bold axis and find the letter in the grid with the corresponding coordinates, so for example LT becomes T. 
>  Translating, our ciphered text becomes 
>  DONTTRUSTTHEKENKU = **DON'T TRUST THE KENKU**
>  This is backed up by the fact that a [Kenku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenku) is a character from *Dungeons & Dragons*.

**Edit:**

> I've just realised "Cabot" and "Fjold" are mentioned in the comments so this must be the answer.